# Look for a tag in an HTML document

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, xcode, html-parsing

I have a url of a web page with one  tag which changes from time to time.
I want to show the user the message inside the  tag without opening a browser.

What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: Request the page with an http client -> parse the html -> show the contents of the tag.

Comment: What is the process of requesting a page with an http client and how do I look at the actual HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of getting the htmldata from a url is

```
//ur url is a object of NSURL
NSError* error;
NSString* html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8String error:&error];
```

The response in html is a response of the url, but the request will be on main thread, if the connection/response time is slow, it will stop the other functions.